# Magento 2: I have a problem with configuring gallery magnifier in product details page

Tags: magento2, product-images, gallery

I'm looking for an effect like the one this site or at least close to it:

https://fashionmix.bg/mazhki-cherni-visoki-ketsove-shagren-it251019-16

But when I configure magnifier in view.xml and set zoom mode to "Inside", there is a square that does not move smoothly.

Is there any chance of achieving what I want or I just should use external plugin for zoom.

P.S. Magento version is 2.3.2

Тhere is not much code to show it is standard Magento functionality, but still, here you are my configuration in etc/view.xml:

```
<var name="magnifier">
  <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>
  <var name="top"></var>
  <var name="left"></var>
  <var name="width"></var>
  <var name="height"></var>
  <var name="eventType">hover</var>
  <var name="enabled">true</var>
  <var name="mode">inside</var>
</var>
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: I updated my post. You can see it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Magento extension for Magic Zoom Plus. It has an internal zoom effect on hover and a full-screen enlarge effect on click - like your example page.

Magento 2:

https://marketplace.magento.com/magictoolbox-magiczoomplus.html

Magento 1:

https://marketplace.magento.com/magictoolbox-magictoolbox-magiczoomplus.html

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want a extension. I just want to know if that is how the built-in zoom works and if there is a way to improve it.

Comment: You asked if you should use external plugin for zoom. Yes, you should, because the default Magento zoom is buggy, you'll spend hours trying to make it work how you want it and it still won't work how you want it. You should also post a link to your website - its infinitely easier to debug a site when you have the URL :)

Comment: Thank you for information. I cannot post a link to website, because it is still under development and how I said in my post there is not much code to show.